# How to make subtotals in power bi matrix visual

Tags: powerbi

I have been googling for a few hours for a solution of this simple task with no luck. I have a simple table

```
Cat         Sales   
Apples       30     
Apples       50     
Apples      100     
Cherries     50     
Cherries     80
```

How do I make Power BI calculate subtotals? Tried Quick Measures, but neither of them works. This is what I get when applying Sum of Sales total for Cat = 
CALCULATE(SUM('Table1'[Sales]), ALLSELECTED('Table1'[Cat])) :

```
Cat         Sales   Sum of Sales total for Cat
Apples       30      30
Apples       50     100
Apples      100     100
Cherries     50     100
Cherries     80      80
```

I am looking to get something like this:

```
Cat         Sales   Sum of Sales total for Cat
Apples       30      30
Apples       50      80
Apples      100     180
Cherries     50      50
Cherries     80     130
```

Comment: Subtitles are automatically enabled when you add more than one field to the Rows input.

Comment: What do you mean by Rows input?

Comment: Each visual takes different input fields, matrix for example takes Rows, Columns and Values. See [this screenshot](https://datasavvy.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/pbi-matrix.png?w=1108). If you add more than one field to the Rows input area of a matrix, subtotals (not subtitles, how did that happen?) should be displayed automatically.

Comment: Ok, you use new Matrix visual. I was trying on the old one. But stll, is it possible to make that individual amounts appear in one column, running total - in the other?

Comment: Is there some kind of date column? how are your sales ordered?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new measure:
Category= Values('Table'[Cat]).

Add this measure in matrix in place of 'Cat' column.